# How to separate a class from rootnode in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

This is the root node that I have

```
     public class rootNode
  {

        public string resourceType { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string WorkflowType { get; set; }
        public string EmrName { get; set; }
        public double EmrVersion { get; set; }
        public Patient patient { get; set; }
  
  }
```

and then I have second class patient

```
  public class Patient
  {
    [Key]
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public string IncomingUniquePatientID { get; set; }
    public string PatientNumber { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int MaritalStatusID { get; set; }
    public int HealthCardNumber { get; set; }
  }
```

and then this is my JSON file

```
   {
    "resourceType": "bundle",
    "type": "resoure",
    "timestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "transactionId": "transactionI",
    "source": null,
    "workflowType": null,
    "emrName": "EMR Name",
    "emrVersion": 0.0,
    "patient": {
        "patientID": 12,
        "incomingUniquePatientID": null,
        "patientNumber": null,
        "gender": 1,
        "dob": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "weight": 32,
        "maritalStatusID": 1,
        "healthCardNumber": 0
    }
}
```

and then this is my controller

```
 public string Post([FromBody] rootNode reqRootModel)
    {
       
        return "Enrollment Saved Successfully.EnrolmentID";
    }
```

How can I separate the patient from rootnode and save it into the Database?

your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I may be missing something, so forgive my ignorance. I am not understanding what you mean by _“separate the patient from rootnode”_ …? A `Patient` is a property OF the `rootNode.` So technically you can’t remove/seperate that property from the `rootNode`, however you can make another stand alone `Patient` object from the `Patient` object in `rootNode`, by cloning it or even a simple reference would work. Can you clarify what you mean by “separate” the `Patient` from the `rootNode.`

Comment: seperate means, I want to take out the value of patient from that JSON that's all

Comment: foreach (rootNode item in reqRootModel)
            {
                var pat = item.patient;
            }

Comment: I tried this but it throws exception

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: foreach-statement-cannot-operate-on-variables-of-type-public-definition-for-get

Comment: Why would you not post the code that throws the error? What is `reqRootModel`? From what I can tell it is a SINGLE `rootNode` object and not a collection. Please update you question with this code. Do not add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

ForEach can only be used on an object that is of Type Collection (list / array).

if you want to create a new object from a property of `rootNode`, you can simply access it via the dot notation.

```
Patient thisPatient = reqRootModel.patient;
```

If patient was a `List<Patient>` in your `rootNode`, then you would iterate over the list via foreach (or for loop). Once you have your patient, you can add that to the respective database table and use SaveContext to add it to your DB.